Setting schedule of onSchedule using environment variables
I'm trying to create a v2 onSchedule Firebase function that has different schedules in different environments. I have each of these schedules stored in different environment files (.env.dev, .env.beta, .env.prod, etc.).
My environment files look something like:
.env.beta, .env.prod:
...
MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE="0 * * * *"

.env.dev:
...
MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE="* * * * *"

Ideally, I would like my function to look something like:
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  /* Some way to get my schedule per environment here */,
  /* My function logic here */
)

I've tried a few approaches so far:
Approach 1 (using process.env)
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler"

const schedule = process.env.MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE!

export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  schedule,
  /* My function logic */
)

This failed, as the schedule is built during compile-time, while process.env fields are available during runtime. I did not receive an error when I built the function, but when I tried to deploy it running my emulator (firebase emulators:start), I got the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'schedule')

Approach 2 (using defineString)
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params"
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler"

const schedule = defineString("MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE")

export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  schedule,
  /* My function logic */
)

In my IDE, I already saw an error showing up:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(schedule: string, handler: (event: ScheduledEvent) => void | Promise<void>): ScheduleFunction', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'StringParam' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: ScheduleOptions, handler: (event: ScheduledEvent) => void | Promise<void>): ScheduleFunction', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'StringParam' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ScheduleOptions'.
      Property 'schedule' is missing in type 'Param<string>' but required in type 'ScheduleOptions'.

When I built the code, I got the same error.
Approach 3 (using defineString with .value())
Similar to the above, the code was nearly identical except for using schedule.value() in the function:
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params"
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler"

const schedule = defineString("MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE")

export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  schedule.value(),
  /* My function logic */
)

This time the function built and when it deployed when I ran firebase emulators:start. However, I received the following warning:
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"params.MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE.value() invoked during function deployment, instead of during runtime."}

{"severity":"WARNING","message":"This is usually a mistake. In configs, use Params directly without calling .value()."}
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"example: { memory: memoryParam } not { memory: memoryParam.value() }"}

This warning is expected, as I'm calling the .value() function during the deployment and not during runtime, as specified in the docs. However, as Approach 2 demonstrated, the recommendation from this warning message doesn't work.
Question
What is the correct way to specify different schedules for a function in different environments?

As covered in the API Reference and the errors in approach 2, there are two ways to call onSchedule to define a scheduled Cloud Function:

onSchedule(schedule: string, handler: (event: ScheduledEvent) => void | Promise<void>) (API Reference)
onSchedule(options: ScheduleOptions, handler: (event: ScheduledEvent) => void | Promise<void>) (API Reference, ScheduleOptions)

Importantly, the first argument is a string or a ScheduleOptions object. You can't provide something else like an Expression as the first argument (defineString() returns a StringParam which is an alias of Expression<string>).
Following suit of other Options objects used as the first argument of other Cloud Functions types, Firebase supports Expressions when using the options-style object like for document in DocumentOptions.
export const myDocCreatedFunction = onDocumentCreated({
  document: defineString("MY_DOCUMENT_PATH")
}, (event) => {
  // your code here
})

Extending this to Scheduled Functions, you would end up with:
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule({
  schedule: defineString("MY_FUNCTION_SCHEDULE")
}, (event) => {
  // your code here
})

For your use case, you might instead write it as:
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  { schedule }, // note braces to make it an object with the shape { schedule: schedule }
  /* My function logic */
)


However, there's a problem with this approach. Looking at the source for the Firebase Functions SDK in /src/v2/providers/scheduler.ts, we can see that ScheduleOptions doesn't accept Expression<string> values.
/** Options that can be set on a Schedule trigger. */
export interface ScheduleOptions extends options.GlobalOptions {
  schedule: string;
  timeZone?: timezone | Expression<string> | ResetValue;
  retryCount?: number | Expression<number> | ResetValue;
  // ...
}

But this seems like an oversight/typo rather than intended behaviour when looking at the git blame for that file. Under the hood, the internal SeparatedOpts type does allow expressions:
/** @hidden */
interface SeparatedOpts {
  schedule: string | Expression<string>;
  timeZone?: timezone | Expression<string> | ResetValue;
  // ...
}

So to get it working as intended, we might need to trick TypeScript until the types are corrected.
// TypeScript
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  {
    // TODO: remove once types corrected (coercing type to
    //       `string` is evil, but better than using `any`)
    schedule: schedule as unknown as string
  },
  /* My function logic */
)

or
// JSDOC
export const myScheduleFunction = onSchedule(
  {
    // TODO: remove once types corrected (coercing type to
    //       `string` is evil, but better than using `any`)
    schedule: /** @type { string } */ (/** @type { unknown } */ (schedule))
  },
  /* My function logic */
)

